# Specify HTML5 - NOT 6?

Tags: html

I've been taking a look at [HTML6](https://www.html6.network/) today, and I dislike it because of having to put `html:` behind each HTML "key" tag (for example, `html:head`).

Because of this I'd like to figure out how to specify that I want to use 5, and **not** 6. Because there isn't a DTD I'm not sure how to do this..

Or perhaps in HTML6, you have to specify something along the lines of `<!DOCTYPE html6>`? However, in all the examples, they just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`...

Comment: To make sure HTML 6 isn't used in a web page, you need to do... exactly nothing. Because it doesn't exist, it isn't going to be implemented in any browsers yet :) in fact, I'm not sure even a draft exists. I know of none. What document have you been looking at?

Comment: I think you are getting confuse reading about this http://html6spec.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from a [handful or proposals](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2015Mar/0066.html) and some [informal](http://www.html6.io/) [definitions](http://html6spec.com/) there is no concept of HTML6.

The confusion is probably arising from the fact that you've been reading examples of how curious people think HTML6 might/should look.

In actuality, HTML5 is the [final revision](http://digitizor.com/2011/01/22/html5-last-version-html/) of the HTML specification.

HTML5 is what's known as a **living standard**. Features will be added to the spec on a rolling basis, which is why the ambiguous `<!DOCTYPE html>` won't cause problems.